# Woocommerce Show Prices With Tax and Without Tax in different colors and on two lines

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using Woocommerce with a Flatsome theme. I want to show the price of each product without and with tax. I have successfully done it. But I am unable to change the color of the Price with Tax. When I used the following CSS then both of the prices changed. I want a different color for both prices. I also want to show both of the prices on two lines.

```
Customise -> Style -> Custom CSS

.product .price .amount {
 color: #900C3F ;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>4.50</bdi>
</span>
<span class="ex-tax"> (ex. tax)</span> 
    <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>4.95</bdi>
    </span>
</small>
<span class="inc-tax"> (incl. tax)</span>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you display Prices With Tax and Without Tax?

Comment: WP Dashboard-> woocommerce ->Settings - Tax Tab   Option: Price  Entered with tax: No, Option: Price display suffix: type (ex tax) {price_including_tax} (inc tax)

Comment: Please also share HTML.

Comment: This is all that I did. Define the taxes first then follow the above steps.  no html used

Comment: No I mean you can inspect elements and check HTML anyway I added the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add CSS like this.

```
.woocommerce-price-suffix span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
    color: blue;
}
span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
    color: red;
}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

**AS per OP requested**

Replace `(ex tax) {price_including_tax} (inc tax)`  with `{price_including_tax}`

[image]

Try the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_css(){
    if( is_product() ){
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .woocommerce-price-suffix span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
                color: blue;
            }
            span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
                color: red;
            }
            span.ex-tax {
                color: red;
            }
            span.inc-tax {
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_css', 10, 1 );

function add_woocommerce_get_price_suffix( $html, $WC_Product, $price, $qty ){
    $html = '<span class="ex-tax">(ex tax)</span>'.$html.'<span class="inc-tax">(inc tax)</span>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'add_woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 999, 4 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How can I change ex tax to red and inc tax to blue?

Comment: This also turns all prices in the cart as red

Comment: WOW that worked for me. Many thanks. I had spent much time on it.

Comment: Yet another problem is that on the Products page it is yet on the products page the text is yet shown with the basic color. I have inspected the code, the class ex-tax is added but has no effect on colors. I have edited the CSS and have added !important with colors but in vain. Also, the products with no tax also include the text suffixes.

Comment: Please add screenshots and HTML to your question.

Comment: I have added two screenshots in my question

Comment: If possible please share your site link.

Comment: Actually, I am not the owner and the site is not public yet. Sharing the html.

Comment: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>4.50</bdi></span><span class="ex-tax"> (ex. tax)</span> <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>4.95</bdi></span></small><span class="inc-tax"> (incl. tax)</span>
 </li>
<li>

Comment: html and images are visible in the question section